# Archimedes's quadrature of a parabola: why point B (half the horizontal lenth across)

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I am looking for pre-calculus proof for the following scenario:

I have a parabola $F(x)$ and a line that goes through $2$ points on given parabola $G(x)$.

If I trace half the horizontal length of the line and from there create a vertical line going through the parabola and the line, the vertical line will hit the parabola exactly in $F'(x)=G'(x)$.

But why? I've seen that this works but cant put it into mathematical proof.

My scenario on [desmos](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/03gqgnpkxu)

[image]

The red lines are the half the horizontal distance of the line they're standing on

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $F(x)=ax^2+bx+c$ and $G(x)=kx+m$. Their intersection points are given by,

$$ax^2+(b-k)x +c -m =0$$

Then, the $x$-coordinate of the vertical intersection is

$$x_m = \frac{x_1+x_2}{2}= -\frac {b-k}{2a}$$

Thus,

$$F'(x_m)= 2a x_m + b = k =G'(x_m)$$

Comment: My hero for answering this so quickly, thanks!

Comment: @brams you're welcome

Answer (score 0):

If you go from the open x=a in both directions the distance d the segment from G(x) goes through (a+d, (a+d)^2) and (a-d, (a-d)^2) the slope of G is ((a+d)^2-(a-d)^2))/2d=4ad/2d=2a
no matter how large or small d is, so al the segments are parallel, and d=0 gives you the tangent.